# CSS put two divs next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm using vue.js and I've tried out using `float: left;` but it won't work. I'm new to vue.js but it should work using normal css under the style right.

My code:

```
<template>
    <div class = "bar">
        <h1 class = "subtitle">Mean {{ field || 'No field yet' }}</h1>
        <div class = "meandata">
            <p>{{ mean.data }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    


</template>

<style>
.bar {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #FEFAE0 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
}

.subtitle{
  font: normal normal normal 20px/20px Sitka Subheading;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #D4A373;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.meandata{
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font: normal normal normal 70px/50px Sylfaen;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #987554;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;

}
</style>
```

Output I got:
[image]

Output that I want:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can this help you?

```css
.bar {
  /*Add*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  /*End Add*/
  width: 400px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #FEFAE0 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: rgba(99, 99, 99, 0.2) 0px 2px 8px 0px;
}

.subtitle{
  font: normal normal normal 20px/20px Sitka Subheading;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: #D4A373;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.meandata{
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font: normal normal normal 70px/50px Sylfaen;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #987554;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 1;

}
```

```html
    <div class = "bar">
        <h1 class = "subtitle">Mean Humidity</h1>
        <div class = "meandata">
            <p>35%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "bar">
        <h1 class = "subtitle">Mean Temperature</h1>
        <div class = "meandata">
            <p>35*</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No problem, gladly done :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put `display:flex` on your first div. This will put the two child elements next to eachother.

Optionally you can also put `justify-content: space-evenly` on the first div to evenly space out the elements within the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="meandata"> << add
   <h1 class = "subtitle">Mean {{ field || 'No field yet' }}</h1>
</div>
<div class="meandata">
    <p>{{ mean.data }}</p>
</div>

 .meandata{
    ....
    overflow:hidden;  << add
  }
```